# Off-CPU flame graphs with perf: what should the types of the output fields be?

Tags: performance, profiling, perf, flamegraph

I've been following [these instructions](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-02-26/linux-perf-off-cpu-flame-graph.html) for generating an off-CPU flame graph for my code. However, when I get to this step:

```
perf script -f comm,pid,tid,cpu,time,period,event,ip,sym,dso,trace
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid field requested.

 Usage: perf script [<options>]
    or: perf script [<options>] record <script> [<record-options>] <command>
    or: perf script [<options>] report <script> [script-args]
    or: perf script [<options>] <script> [<record-options>] <command>
    or: perf script [<options>] <top-script> [script-args]

    -F, --fields <str>    comma separated output fields prepend with 'type:'. Valid types: hw,sw,trace,raw. Fields: comm,tid,pid,time,cpu,event,trace,ip,sym,dso,addr,symoff,period,iregs,brstack,brstacksym,flags,bpf-output,callindent,insn,insnlen
```

I understand that each of the output fields needs to have a type, but I am unsure which type(s) I should be providing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is your linux kernel version? Was your perf updated to your kernel version too? Instructions are [for 3.19](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph/issues/47#issuecomment-76298637); for 4.5 linux also "`echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_schedstats`" is needed. Try to delete some fields from the perf script to find one which is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Update: on more recent kernels, use "perf script -F ..." instead of "perf script -f ...". Your kernel will also need CONFIG_SCHEDSTATS for the tracepoints to all be present, which may be missing (eg, RHEL7).

Note, please set the /proc/sys/kernel/sched_schedstats to 1 before you draw the off-cpu flamegraph.